# DataTables warning: table id=document_table - Invalid JSON response

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I am trying to create a jquery data table using php but I am receiving this error : DataTables warning: table id=document_table - Invalid JSON response.

Here is my code:

documents.php

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
    <title>Central American Management</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div>
         <input type="hidden" id="UserId" name="UserId" data-id="<?php echo($_SESSION['UserId'])?>"></input>
        
        
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="container">
         <div class="btnAdd">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md" id="add-document"><i class="fa fa-plus " aria-hidden="true">
            </i><span>Add Document</span></button>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-2"></div>
               <div class="col-md-8"> 
               <table id="document_table" class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>ID</th>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Country</th>
                      <th>Shared</th>
                      <th>Uploaded BY</th>
                      <th>Uploaded Date</th>
                      <th>Options</th>
                     </tr>
                 </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
               </table>
               </div>
                 <div class="col-md-2"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-container" id="modal-container"></div>
<script src="../javascriptfiles/Documents.js"></script>

 
  </body>
</html>
```

Documents.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = function( settings, helpPage, message){
              console.log(message);
    };
    $('#document_table').dataTable({
         "fnCreatedRow": function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex ) {
          $(nRow).attr('documentId', aData[0]);
        },
       'processing':true,
       'serverSide':true,
        'paging':'true',
        'order' :[],
       'ajax': {
        'url': "//centralamericanmanagement.000webhostapp.com/phpfiles/getDocuments.php",
        'type': "POST"
        },
       "columnDefs": [{
          'target':[6],
          'orderable' :false,
        }]
    }); 
  
});
```

server-side code

```
<?php
require_once '../DBConnection/dbConfig.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `getDocuments`";
$temp = $dbh->query($sql);
$total_all_rows =$temp->fetchColumn() ; 
if(isset($_POST['search']['value']))
{
    $search_value = $_POST['search']['value'];
    $sql .= " WHERE document_name like '%".$search_value."%'";
    $sql .= " OR country_name like '%".$search_value."%'";
    $sql .= " OR user like '%".$search_value."%'";
}
if(isset($_POST['order']))
{
    $column_name = $_POST['order'][0]['column'];
    $order = $_POST['order'][0]['dir'];
    $sql .= " ORDER BY ".$column_name." ".$order."";
}
else
{
    $sql .= " ORDER BY documentId desc";
}
if($_POST['length'] != -1)
{
    $start = $_POST['start'];
    $length = $_POST['length'];
    $sql .= " LIMIT  ".$start.", ".$length;
}
try {
    $query = $dbh->query($sql);
    $count_rows = $query->fetchColumn();
    $data = array();
     
     
    foreach($results as $row)
    {
        $sub_array = array();
        $sub_array[] = $row["documentId"];
        $sub_array[] = $row["document_name"];
        $sub_array[] = $row["country_name"];
        $sub_array[] = $row["shared"];
        $sub_array[] = $row["user"];
        $sub_array[] = $row["uploadDate"];
        $sub_array[] = '<a href="javascript:void();" data-id="'.$row['documentId'].'"  class="btn btn-info btn-sm editbtn" >Edit</a>  <a href="javascript:void();" data-id="'.$row['documentId'].'"  class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deleteBtn" >Delete</a>';
        $data[] = $sub_array;
    }
    $output = array(
        'draw'=> intval($_POST['draw']),
        'recordsTotal' =>$count_rows ,
        'recordsFiltered'=>$total_all_rows,
        'data' => $data
        
    );
   
      echo json_encode($output);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e){
         echo json_encode("Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>");
    }

?>
```

I have been looking at this for sometime now and after doing much research I am still not understanding where this error is coming from.

Comment: The issue seems to be about JSON, but the question is missing the JSON?

Comment: The JSON Data is created in the server-side code

Comment: Nothing looks off to me, but a few things that you could do: 1. Check the browser's console to ensure no javascript errors. 2. Check the browser's network tab to see the ajax request response, which might have some other data (such as an error) that is not json. 3. Echo out the encoded json, and then copy/paste that into an online json validator (such as [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com/), but there are other sites) to see what the complaints may be. You might be able to copy the json from the network response info as well.